# Programming on Highly Distributed Clusters

Tags: amazon-ec2, distributed

I want to practice programming on a distributed cluster and I would like to not have to pay. I know about Amazon EC2, but it is not free up to a certain usage kind of thing.

Is there anything like this?

Comment: EC2 is not expensive, if you are just practicing.  if you are running huge jobs, then I doubt you will find anyone willing to give you free computer time.  maybe you need to create a worm and start collecting exploited machines for a botnet :)

Comment: Hmm.. there is a community cloud available, very similar to EC2 see: http://open.eucalyptus.com/CommunityCloud

Only they have restrictions like how many hours the instance will be available, etc.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create cluster locally? You can install SW like VirtualBox and create virtual servers. There are some linux distributions that are ready to be installed on virtual server, e.g. [turnkey linux](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/).

Or if you have computers to spare you can play with [Eucalyptus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucalyptus_(computing)).

Comment: This is actually the best choice

Answer (score 0):

With Microsoft Azure you can simulate the cloud on your local machine for development and testing. You can also get a 1-month free trial account for the real Azure platform (I believe) to test your cloud service live.